# Querying inside a blade view in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

hi i was trying to do a query like

```
{{ \App\User::where(['name' => $posts->username])->pluck('avatar') }}
```

however this query outputs something like this

```
["1486468548.jpg"]
```

i was expecting

```
1486468548.jpg
```

so that it can actually be read. any ideas on how to remove the blocks and quotes??? i know it is not a good practise to query in blade but with my code flow i dont know how else to ge the user avatars.

My controller looks like this. its where the posts are generated from. is there a way i can get the user avatar with a value of **posts** table. I know it exists but i dont know how

```
public function getDashboard()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    return view('home', ['post' => $posts]);
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4 `pluck()` returns a Collection of those values (even if there is only one).

You can either do:

```
\App\User::where(['name' => $posts->username])->pluck('avatar')->first();
```

or

```
\App\User::where(['name' => $posts->username])->first()->avatar;
```

That being said I would also suggest creating a relationship between `Post`s and `User`s so that you can eager load the relationships so that you're:

1. Not having to query inside you view (that logic shouldn't really be in there).
2. You not performing multiple queries when you don't need to

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/15
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Then you could load the posts with the users:

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

and get the avatar by:

```
$post->user->avatar;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Wring the query under @php. And then print the value of the array below. Like as example

```
@php 
$value = \App\User::where(['name' => $posts->username])->pluck('avatar')
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
{{ \App\User::where(['name' => $posts->username])->pluck('avatar')->first() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the cool way , simply add [0] at end and done

```
\App\User::where(['name' => $posts->username])->pluck('avatar')[0]
```